# Bottom of border is missing

Tags: html, css, background

My bottom border is missing. I've tried everything. Now I'm just making stupid changes. Plus my navigation links are backwards. I've read the stack overflow posts regarding this, but nothing is working for me. They should be Home About Us Our Services... but they are reversed.

```
/* HEADER AREA
---------------------------------*/
#header {
position: absolute;       
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;     
    height: 185px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #b2c248;
        border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 1px thick #ff00ff;
    z-index: -1;

/* MAIN NAVIGATION
---------------------------------*/
#nav {
    float: right; 
    width: 100%;
    <!-- width: 900px; -->
    height: 53px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: right; 
    line-height: 53px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a shame... did you have a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `thick` isn't a valid `border-style`. Change it to, for instance, `solid` and it should be visible.

As for the elements appearing in reverese; it's because you `float` them to the right. Use `float: left` instead and you'll be fine. If you want the elements to appear on the right but still use their original order, set `float: right` to their parent element (the `ul`) instead.

Comment: Bless you. I could've sworn that I did that. Thank you.